# How to build/create simple OpenOffice.org extensions/add-ons?

Tags: perl, openoffice.org

What are the some of the requirements to create simple OpenOffice.org extensions? 
I have Perl Program that runs standalone. With this Perl script, I want to create OpenOffice extension.

References to tutorials can also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to look no further than the Developer's wiki and search for Perl: [Developer's Guide](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide)
AFAIK, anyways, it's easier to develop them using python and Javascript. Depending on what you waht to do, it might be easier to use some OO services using CPAN modules from within a Perl program

Comment: Hi I want further help in this regarding. Some kick start tutorial to make UI components of plugin and accessing main document window and inject text int it